# "Random" SQL Error - General 1030, -1 from storage engine

Tags: mysql, pdo

Full error:

```
Fatal Error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error -1 from storage engine'
in C:\MyApacheDir\MyPHPFile.php:33
```

Line 33 is the `->execute()` of my PDO prepared statement. This behaviour does not always occur; when performing the exact same action, it might not happen.

My query:

```
// Make new permissions
$sql = "INSERT INTO permissions (
      doc_id,
      user_id,
      write_access 
    ) VALUES (
      :doc_id,
      :user_id,
      :write_access
    );";
$stmt = $dbConn->prepare($sql);

ForEach ($permitArr as $permit) {
  $stmt->bindValue(":doc_id", $_POST['doc_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue(":user_id", $permit[0], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue(":write_access", $permit[1], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

where `permitArr` contains an array of permissions of the form `Array[index][info]` where `[info]` is either 0 or 1 corresponding to user and access level respectively.

As stated, this error only occurs sometimes; other iterations of the exact same query (literally, identical information is passed) work fine.

Does anybody know what the `-1` error code is caused from? Maybe it's just inferior search skills, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I'm working off of an Apache 2.2 localhost with MySQL 5.6 in IE8.

Comment: What's in MySQL server's logs? Looks like the error you quoted is from the PHP logs, but the MySQL logs may offer some additional insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fishy. I can't find an error with that number, so that normally means there is an outside factor at play. I would try the following:

1.) Create a new table and try the code on the new table.

2.) Create a new schema with a new table and try the code again.

3.) Run chkdsk on your drive to make sure there aren't any cluster problems.

4.) Reboot.

Comment: I'll try these when I get some more time. I'll try to report back ASAP. There aren't a lot of entries in this table (only 3, actually, at time of error). No other tables are having this problem. Hopefully this is localized (as I'm really only developing locally, then migrating to the server).

Comment: I did a `TRUNCATE TABLE permissions`, and so far, that seems to have solved it... My guess is that something was corrupt in that table, so when `TRUNCATE` dropped it and created it anew it works again. Very odd that it was only an intermittent problem.